# Retrieve unique rows based on id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

Report

```
ReportId CreatedDate
   1     2018-01-12
   2     2018-02-12
   3     2018-03-12
```

ReportSpecialty

```
SpecialtyId ReportId IsPrimarySpecialty
     1          1           1
     2          2           1
     3          3           1
     1          2           0
     1          3           0
```

I am trying to write a query that will retrieve me the last 10 reports that were published. However, I need to get 1 report from each specialty. Assume there are 100 specialties, I can pass in as an argument any number of specialties, 10, 20, 5, 2, etc...

I'm trying to figure out a way where if I send it all specialties, it will get me the last 10 reports posted based on the last date created, but it won't give me 2 articles from same specialty. If I send it 10 specialties, then I will get 1 of each. If I send it 5, then I'll get 2 of each. If I send it 3 then I'll get 4 of 1 and 3 of other two.

I may need to write multiple queries for this, I'm trying to see if there is a way to do this on the SQL side of things? If there isn't, then how would I break down to multiple queries to get the result I want?

What I have tried is this, however I get multiple reports with same specialties:

```
SELECT TOP 10  r.ReportId, rs.SpecialtyId, r.CreatedDate
FROM Report r
INNER JOIN ReportSpecialty rs ON r.ReportId = rs.ReportId AND rs.IsPrimarySpecialty = 1
GROUP BY rs.SpecialtyId, r.AceReportid, r.CreatedDate
ORDER BY r.CreatedDate DESC
```

Comment: Show us what queries you tried.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with cte as (
     SELECT R.ReportId, R.CreatedDate, RS.SpecialtyId,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RS.SpecialtyId 
                               ORDER BY R.CreatedDate DESC) as rn

     FROM Report R
     JOIN ReportSpecialty  RS
       ON R.ReportId = RS.ReportId 
      AND RS.IsPrimarySpecialty = 1
     WHERE RS.SpecialtyId IN ( .... ids ... )
)

 SELECT TOP 10 *
 FROM cte
 ORDER BY rn, CreatedDate DESC
```

row_number will create a id for each speciality, so if you pass 3 speciality you will get something like this.

```
 rn speciality_id
  1     1
  1     2
  1     3
  2     1
  2     2
  2     3
  3     1
  3     2
  3     3
```

Comment: You are missing DESC on R.CreatedDate in the Partition, but other than that I think this works.

Comment: One other thing about this, if I remove the WHERE clause because lets say I want all specialties, I noticed that it prioritizes them by Specialty Id as oppose to Created Date.

Comment: Actually you wrote `based on the date created`, so you missed that information on the question. You didnt specify if you want the latest or the earliest. ;)

Comment: Again, in your question you said you want return an evenly distribution based on speciality. That is what I did. And that I why I write the comment you need provide sample data and expected output. Otherwise Is a guessing game.

Comment: Wouldn't  `ORDER BY rn, CreatedDate DESC` instead of `ORDER BY rn, SpecialtyId` solve the problem.

Comment: Ohh forget about the last one. Yes, that may be what you need

Comment: Interesting, I ran the query like that and the results I'm getting is what I expect.